# Mongodb inserting doc without _id field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-query

I am newbie to mongodb.

1. I need to insert a doc without the _id field generating automatically.
2. I need to set the field Tenant_id as unique or need to change the "_id" field to Tenant_id.

how to do it?

something like this

```
     Tenant
        {Tenant_id: 123, Tenant_info: ...}
```

Comment: I'm also wondering about the _class field.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By default, all regular collections automatically insert an _id field if it is absent.

**Since MongoDB v4.0 there is no way to not have the `_id` field**

**For MongoDB versions v4.0 and below:**

However, this behavior can be changed when you create the collection, by setting explicitely the autoIndexId parameter to false.

```
> db.createCollection("noautoid", { autoIndexId: false })
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Then you can insert documents without _id field. But some drivers, like the javascript one (and so the mongo console), add the _id field by themselves. In the mongo console, you can do this:

```
> db.noautoid._mongo.insert(db.noautoid._fullName, {name: "Jack"})
> db.noautoid.find()
{ "name" : "Jack" }
```

More information about the autoIndexId field can be found in the [MongoDB documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections#CappedCollections-autoIndexId). This page is about Capped Collections but the autoIndexId field is common to both regular and capped collections.

Comment: It is no longer allowed - _id field is required for replication and therefore should always exist.

Answer (score 4):

The `_id` field is the default key for a mongo document unless you are using capped collections.

It is an umutable field which cannot be left out of a document structure.

I would recommend using `tennant_id` as `_id` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Mongodb will automatically generate the '_id' field only if you do not specify a value for the '_id' field when you insert a document. So you can just manually set the _id when you insert the document:

```
db.tenants.insert( {"_id" : 123, "Tenant_info" : ... } )
```

Answer (score 2):

Every MongoDB document must have a unique field "_id" and if you don't provide it then it will be automatically generated for you.

It is not possible to rename this field.

Your two choices are:

1) ignore the generated _id field and use your own tenant_id field  (you will need to add a unique index on that field)
or 
2) store tenant_id value in the _id field (and take advantage of the fact that it already has a unique index on it).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to remove _id field in any mongodb collections.
As, @stephene said,I tried the same, but iam getting error like this

```
> db.noautoid._mongo.insert(db.noautoid._fullName, {name: "Jack"});
 2015-06-18T11:22:29.149+0530 E QUERY    Error: insert needs 3 args
 at (shell):1:20
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongo states in https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#definition

> Starting in MongoDB 4.0, you cannot set the option autoIndexId to
> false when creating collections in databases other than the local
> database.

[image]