# MongoDb insert() is putting _id into my objects and I don't want them

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

If I have an array of objects, say

```
var myArray = [
  { name: 'Fred', state: 'CA' },
  { name: 'Jane', state: 'DE' }
];
```

and insert them into a mongo collection (I'm using node.js and the "standard" npm mongo driver, npmjs.org/package/mongodb)

```
someCollection.insert(myArray, errCallback);
```

I was slightly surprised that the resulting objects (in memory - looking with the debugger) now have the added _id field.

Is there an option to avoid this?  In some ways having the _id is a good thing, in fact, I wrote some extra code cause I didn't think it would be there!  But I want to print them out as JSON etc. and the end user probably doesn't want to see stuff like

```
"name" : "Fred",
"_id": "52caeb50559518c01ab1dda5"
```

(plus possible security issue)

Obviously, I could adjust my printing code, but for the future it might be nice to avoid this, or at least know how to.  If it cant be avoided, I will definitely have to write my own ID generator.

Looking at the docs (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html) I see a forceServerObjectId but that's not what I want.

Comment: Answered previously here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378320/mongodb-inserting-doc-without-id-field

Comment: @gview Thanks.  Alas, their suggested solution, {autoIndexId: false}, is not listed as an option when creating a collection in node's mongo driver.

Comment: My personal opinion is that you're trying to go a long way to disable something intrinsic to mongodb that you may find you need later.  You can also override the built-in key generation and replace it with a key of your own choosing if that appeals to you, but your post suggests you already knew about that.  If you think you ever may need to shard, you might want to consider what your shard key may be as well.  The thing about shard keys is that they can not be changed once set, so even if you have a multi-segmented shard key none of the components can be changeable.

Comment: @gview After some consideration, I agree with you.  Simply adding my own key generator will help with a lot of things, and that way I am "working with" Mongo instead of fighting against it.

Comment: @gview Unless somebody comes up with something brilliant in the next day or two, if you make your comment an answer I'll "accept" it.

Comment: no worries on the points, I don't think i really answered your question, but it might be good to post to the one I linked to, your comments about the fact that you could not set the needed options in the node driver.  Overall, if this question helps others in the future get clarity faster, then we've all won.

Comment: @gview On rereading the docs, looks like autoIndexId is valid for db.createCollection().  It is just not listed under new Collection.  I hate blundering through the MongoDb docs.  So, looks like the "may already have an answer here" comment is true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the node.js driver, but I can attest to the default behavior of the default MongoDB shell. When you do a normal db.collection.find( {query}, {fields}) query, the _id field is automatically included as part of the output. To remove the _id field, you need to explicitly state `_id : 0` in the field selection for the output. The behavior could be similar in the node.js driver.

Comment: I (was) using the `{_id:0}` option on finds(), and it does work with the Node driver.  My problem is that when I do an insert() the _ids are added to the in-memory objects.