# How to rename the field name in Spring-mongodb when data insert?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I using spring mongodb to my project.When I insert the data of this class:

```
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String personId;

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<String> friends;
    private Date tempValue;
}
```

It insert to mongodb:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("543de17f2e631eb39036e60a"),
  "name" : "Johnathan",
  "age" : 73,
  "friends" : ["hh", "hhhh", "hoho"],
  "tempValue" : ISODate("2014-10-15T02:52:47.721Z")
}
```

I want to change the field name of "tempIntergeValue" to "temp_value",it will be more like database name rule.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Simply annotate your field with `@Field` as follows:

```
@Field("temp_value")
private Date tempValue;
```

Comment: Can we specify some other name to the **_id** field? If yes, then how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `_id` is a special field in Mongo, so every document must have it. See Asya Kamsky's comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12384878/1333610