# How can I save names of json objects different than the variable name in Springboot?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, spring-boot

I want the object names of my json file to be different than their variable names. How can I do that while saving it in a database such as MongoDB?

```
public class Data {
@SerializedName("class_id")
private Integer id;

@SerializedName("class_name")
private String name;

@SerializedName("class_type")
private String type;

@SerializedName("class_code")
private String code;
}
```

The following entity is saved as:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Andy",
  "type": "fun",
  "code": "0023"
}
```

but I want to save it as:

```
{
      "class_id": "1",
      "class_name": "Andy",
      "class_type": "fun",
      "class_code": "0023"
 }
```

I can't use snake case in my variable names as I am only allowed camel case but names need to be saved in snake case.
Please help out! Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373772/how-to-rename-the-field-name-in-spring-mongodb-when-data-insert/26373886

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't find the question earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring Data Mongo there is a @Field annotation which allows you to customize the field name.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-annotations