# Modify Mongodb source code to disable auto-generating "_id" field for doc

Tags: c++, mongodb

I want to modify and compile the latest source code of mongodb(as of now, mongodb version v3.5.10-34-g27d21e6 from [github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo)) to make the **_id** field not automatically generated if not provided when inserting a document. The current official release of mongodb requires the existence of this field (I have tested this fact on mongodb-win32-x86_64-v3.4-latest from https://www.mongodb.org) .

I found a related question [Mongodb inserting doc without _id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378320/mongodb-inserting-doc-without-id-field/12384878#12384878). But I think my question does not duplicate with this one because mine is asking for source code modification while this one is about parameter setting (whose answers are also no longer workable for current version of mongodb).

I know that the official mongodb group have their reasons and considerations to  require such an **_id** field and since they have decided to introduce such a requirement, it's not likely that they will remove it in the near future. And I also know that disabling **_id** will affect some functionality of mongodb such as replication mentioned above. But I still want to know how to disable it since I will just use it as a personal database running only one instance on a single machine. I am sure I won't need other functionalities. Storage is what I considered most so I don't want this field take additional disk space. And for the same reason I need the wiredTiger engine with the compression abilities so I need to do this to a relatively new version of mongodb.

As of now, I have successfully compiled and linked the original source code v3.5.10-34-g27d21e6 using scons with VS2015 installed. So I hope someone can tell me which code segment/segments of which source code file/files I should modify to disable auto-generating **_id** field; and which files also need to be "patched" that would check the existence of **_id** and refuse to work properly if not found even if they don't really need it.

The below two files are what I have found that seems related:

1) mongo/src/mongo/db/ops/insert.cpp line:153-177

I tried to modify this file as follows but after which **_id** is still auto created

from:

```
if (firstElementIsId) {
        b.append(doc.firstElement());
        i.next();
    } else {
        BSONElement e = doc["_id"];
        if (e.type()) {
            b.append(e);
        } else {
            b.appendOID("_id", NULL, true);
        }
    }

    while (i.more()) {
        BSONElement e = i.next();
        if (hadId && e.fieldNameStringData() == "_id") {
            // no-op
        } else if (e.type() == bsonTimestamp && e.timestampValue() == 0) {
            auto nextTime = LogicalClock::get(service)->reserveTicks(1);
            b.append(e.fieldName(), nextTime.asTimestamp());
        } else {
            b.append(e);
        }
    }
```

to:

```
if (firstElementIsId) {
        //b.append(doc.firstElement());
        i.next();
    } else {
        BSONElement e = doc["_id"];
        if (e.type()) {
            //b.append(e);
        } else {
            //b.appendOID("_id", NULL, true);
        }
    }

    while (i.more()) {
        BSONElement e = i.next();
        if (hadId && e.fieldNameStringData() == "_id") {
            // no-op
        } else if (e.fieldNameStringData() == "_id") {
            // no-op
        } else if (e.type() == bsonTimestamp && e.timestampValue() == 0) {
            auto nextTime = LogicalClock::get(service)->reserveTicks(1);
            b.append(e.fieldName(), nextTime.asTimestamp());
        } else {
            b.append(e);
        }
    }
```

2) mongo/src/mongo/bson/bsonobj.cpp line:281-315

I didn't modify this file because I didn't see which line of code may add the **_id** field, just feel it may related to the question from what it mentioned in its comment.

```
/* note: addFields always adds _id even if not specified
   returns n added not counting _id unless requested.
*/
int BSONObj::addFields(BSONObj& from, set<string>& fields) {
    verify(isEmpty() && !isOwned()); /* partial implementation for now... */

    BSONObjBuilder b;

    int N = fields.size();
    int n = 0;
    BSONObjIterator i(from);
    bool gotId = false;
    while (i.moreWithEOO()) {
        BSONElement e = i.next();
        const char* fname = e.fieldName();
        if (fields.count(fname)) {
            b.append(e);
            ++n;
            gotId = gotId || strcmp(fname, "_id") == 0;
            if (n == N && gotId)
                break;
        } else if (strcmp(fname, "_id") == 0) {
            b.append(e);
            gotId = true;
            if (n == N && gotId)
                break;
        }
    }

    if (n) {
        *this = b.obj();
    }

    return n;
}
```

So, that's pretty what I have done now.
I am not familiar with the mongodb source code structure and its really a huge project for me to understand. Looking forward to a detailed To-Do list that I can follow to modify the code without too much knowledge is required about how mongodb works. But of course, any other type of information that is related is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per the related question you mentioned, default `_id` values can be overridden when inserting documents. What is your goal in hacking the server code? This seems a long path to possibly save a few bytes and is likely to cause subtle breakage unless you test thoroughly. If you are going to make changes, I would suggest using a stable branch (v3.4) rather than a dev branch (v3.5 / master). If you like WiredTiger but don't want the benefits/overhead of a distributed database or query planner, you could also consider using the [WiredTiger library](http://source.wiredtiger.com) directly.

Comment: @Stennie **About space saved:** Yes, for each doc, maybe only a few bytes could be saved. But in my case, each doc is in itself very short in general, the **_id** field still take a non-neglectable proportion of capacity and this will accumulate with a lot of docs added. Since this is for personal use, I can't just add more disk like the companies and I am already in short of disk space on my PC.  So I just want to squeeze the disk space with compression and removing unnecessary fields, as much as possible.

Comment: @Stennie **About the difficulty:** I am not familiar with the source code of mongodb and I have no clear recognition on the difficulty of this hacking thing. I am hoping that the source code was so considerately designed that there would be some magic switch/switches waiting for me to discover that can easily do the trick and it's only me who is not familiar with the code that can not find it/them easily. And I am still hoping this is the case.

Comment: @Stennie **About the version:** Yes, I agree, v3.4 will be better, I will try it, thanks for the tip. **And about WiredTiger**, I think your recommendation is attractive for me since it will satisfy my requirement most. But considering the difficulty and time investment needed to learn how to program with WiredTiger library which I currently have no much idea about except that it support compression and row-level lock, I think patching some code of Mongodb seems relatively more preferable and practical for me. But I will leave the door open, thanks for the info.

Comment: why don't you rename one of the existing fields you will already be using "_id" (and then make sure no unique index exists on _id when you create the collection)?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Firstly, there is no such a field in my collection that will be guaranteed to be existing in every document that will be inserted. Secondly, even if there is such a field, I don't think it's quite elegant to change its name to "_id" no matter what its real meaning is. I prefer keeping the field name more descriptive.

Comment: Anything is more elegant than breaking a fundamental assumption in the database by changing its source code.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Hi, thanks for the input. I admit that what I am trying to do will definately break the elegance of the mongodb software. But on the other hand, I think the content stored and presented by the database would looks better. I feel they belong to different perspectives. Like "Drawing a bad graph on an elegant notebook" v.s. "Drawing an elegant graph on a randomly picked piece of paper or even on the street wall". Of course it would be better if both the medium and the content are elegant. But if I have to make a choice, I prefer the latter.

Answer (score 1):

In that 3rd code snippet you posted, replacing `bool gotId = false` with `bool gotId = true` may make it behave as you want - but it also may break things.

You mentioned the reason you began this is to improve storage performance - is removing one field really going to make a sizeable difference? I'd be surprised if it did. What's a lot more likely is that some functionality that you *do* desire will break (perhaps not now, perhaps a long time down the line at a point where you least expect it).

Warnings aside, you said you wanted :

> a detailed To-Do list that I can follow to modify the code

It's unlikely you'll find someone familiar enough with the MongoDB source to the level where they could tell you if it's safe/unsafe and how to remove this field on StackOverflow - you're more likely to get a response by trying to contact the dev team, or at least people who add code to the [open source effort](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo). As a final warning though, it's unlikely you'll find anyone even there who'll take the time to list the steps. Modifications like this tend to require a large devotion of time to understand the source - there's no easy fix.

Comment: I just tried replacing `bool gotId = false` with `bool gotId = true`, but it didn't work, **_id** is still generated. I think the storage performance that can be achieved depends on the length of the documents inserted. If each one is very short, as in my case, it is still worth a try for me. I know a To-Do list must be hard to find on stackoverflow, but since the feature I want is what the mongodb officials have taken time to consider not to support anymore, I think this question fits here more. But I will still try to find someone from the dev team to help me. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do right now is not going to work. _id is essentially the primary key and in many places in the code there is an assumption that the _id field is present (and of course unique). If you are not very familiar with the idea of primary keys, think of it as unique record identification in the database. No identification == no record.

What is the specific benefit that you're seeking? You should rephrase your question and ask people how to achieve that instead.

Good luck!

Comment: **_id** is unique by default in mongodb. When a document is inserted with no **_id** specified, mongodb will auto-create one of type **ObjectId** and assure its uniqueness by applying a unique index on **_id**. However, if  **{autoIndexID : false}** is specified when creating a collection, no unique index on **_id** will be created therefore no duplication checking will be performed;and now if docs with duplicate **_id** are inserted, the **_id** field will be non-unique in the collection. `autoIndexID` is claimed deprecated since v3.2 but as of my test on v3.5.10-34-g27d21e6, it still works.

Comment: What I am seeking is some additional storage reduction by disable auto-generating the **_id** field and its corresponding index. I know there are workarounds such as set autoIndexID to false while creating the collection to disable index and assign a pseudo-value for **_id** with minimum lenght value to suppress the system from auto-generating a long one. But I feel the resulted collection is not elegant with those  pseudo-values for **_id** which I know I will never use. Plus I can get additional storage reduction if the **_id** filed can be totally removed. So i want to modified the code.

Comment: Why don't you pass the smallest possible _id field them?  Say null.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I think I will pass the smallest possible **_id** as a workaround if I can't finally find the correct way to modify the source code. But I still hope the code can be modified to totally disable the **_id** field to keep the data stored in the db looks more neat. BTW, as you suggested, **null** looks like a good candidate. So do you have some info about how many bits a **null** does cost? Thanks