# Serialization of Mongo objects leaves a '_id' and '_class' field in the json. How can I turn that off?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, spring-boot, serialization

Serialization of Mongo objects leaves an `_id` and `_class` field in the json. I could live with `_id`  but I would like to remove `_class` field from the JSON.

I have a Spring-Boot app reading JSON from a Mongo db.

How can I turn it off, so that only the objects explicit fields are saved into the Mongo json document (on the write)?

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "618da8804b421f7f5e1e756c"
    },
    ...
    "_class": "com.whatever.my.ApplicationObj"
}
```

NOTE1: `_id` is mentioned [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/serialization/) as being a 'read-only' field:

NOTE2: `_class` is mentioned [here](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-insert-mongodb-document-using-spring-data-part-2-1090) also:

NOTE3: `_id` is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378320/mongodb-inserting-doc-without-id-field) as being required.

Do I need a custom serializer?